# Can I simplify this code to one line

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

Is it possible to simplify this and use it in one line only, without `if (strFilter == "")` :

```
if (strFilter == "")
{
    IList<User> users = Context.Users.Where(u => u.Location == "UK").ToList();
}
else
{
    IList<User> users = Context.Users.Where(u => u.Location == "UK" && u.JobTitle == strFilter).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile at all since `Where` returns `IEnumerable<T>` not a single object `User`.

Comment: Also, one-liners are not always better than a clear `if..else`. But you need to declare `User` outside, then you can initialize it in the `if...else` and access it afterwards.

Comment: Avoid `strFilter == ""`, use instead `string.IsNullOrEmpty(strFilter)`

Comment: Yes you are right Tim, corrected.

Comment: @Whistler: still incorrect, `ToList` returns a `List<User>` not a single `User`.

Comment: Corrected, thanks for pointing that out, my real code was more complex, I have simplified it for the example and made few mistake :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
var users = Context.Users.Where(u => u.Location == "UK" && (strFilter == "" || u.JobTitle == strFilter));
```

Comment: Wow, amazing, so simple. Thank you

Comment: Also @Whistler, it's worth noting that this solution rightly identifies that the original linq statement returns a collection of a users rather than a single user.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this, using a conditional operator:

```
 User user = Context.Users.Where(u => u.Location == "" ? u.Location == "" : u.Location == "UK" && u.JobTitle == strFilter);
```

Comment: Yes, a nice example why you often should prefer an `if...else` ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I was little late to post.So the exact answer was posted before me. So i do it in a different way.